# How to Convert Chr to Date in R Using Lubridate (month.day)?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Hi I have a data frame (`df`) that looks like:

```
Date
Jun.1
Jan.1
Jul.3
Mar.1
```

It's a character type.

Trying to use the lubridate package to convert to a date type. However, the closest thing I can find is `mdy` which converts when the format is e.g. January 31st, 2017.

So, I tried to replace all the '.' to '' using `gsub('.', '', df$date)`, but this just returns NAs.

Any advice?

Comment: What is the expected year Try `mdy(df$Date, truncated = 2)` if it is 2020

Comment: There is no year in the dataset, but all data from 2020 @akrun

Comment: Please check the solution I posted.  Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the `truncated` in `mdy` to make up for the missing component.  It will return the current 'year' as it is missing

```
df$Date <- mdy(df$Date, truncated = 2)
df$Date
#[1] "2020-06-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-07-03" "2020-03-01"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("Jun.1", "Jan.1", "Jul.3", "Mar.1")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```